# Cannot declare 'TimeAgoPipe' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I am getting an error in `Angular 10` while doing `ng build --prod`. It works in `ng build`.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:44:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'TimeAgoPipe' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

44     TimeAgoPipe,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/time-ago-pipe/time-ago.pipe.d.ts:3:22
    3 export declare class TimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'TimeAgoPipe' is declared here.
```

This is the file inside `node_modules/time-ago-pipe/time-ago.pipe.d.ts`

```
import { PipeTransform, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare class TimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
    private changeDetectorRef;
    private ngZone;
    private timer;
    constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, ngZone: NgZone);
    transform(value: string): string;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
    private removeTimer();
    private getSecondsUntilUpdate(seconds);
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<TimeAgoPipe, never>;
    static ɵpipe: ɵngcc0.ɵɵPipeDefWithMeta<TimeAgoPipe, "timeAgo">;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=time-ago.pipe.d.ts.map
```

This is how I am using this in `app.module.ts` file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TimeAgoPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [LastseenDevicesComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

This package is not maintained for 3 years, I would recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pipes#timeago and you can find more details about this issue here https://github.com/AndrewPoyntz/time-ago-pipe/issues/33

this solution worked for some people

```
...
import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

@Pipe({
    name: 'timeAgo',
    pure: false
})
export class TimeAgoExtendsPipe extends TimeAgoPipe {}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TimeAgoExtendsPipe,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `TimeAgoPipe` to `exports` array of `app.module` as well.

Comment: In `app.module.ts` there is no `export` array seems.

Comment: You can add `exports` array just like `imports`.

Comment: Tried this but same error `exports: [TimeAgoPipe],`.